# ¿Cómo puedo abrir una ventana modal en React JS al cargar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs

Mi intención es hacer que al cargar la página web muestre una ventana modal con una imagen desde un componente de react.

Ejemplo desde el componente modal.js:

```
app.js => index.html
```

¿Qué evento debo llamar para poder hacerlo?

Comment: Porque no creas un evento que llame a una función para mostrar el modal. En react podrías hacerlo con los hooks  useState , useEffect

Comment: ¿Estás usando hooks o class components? La respuesta variará de acuerdo a ello. Por favor date una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio y no olvides proporcionarnos código, preferentemente a través de un [Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2876/).

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.